# Ratio of the number of English and Chinese books

Tags: word-problem, ratio

In a library, the ratio of the number of English books to the number of Chinese books was 8:5. After the librarians bought 50 more Chinese books, the ratio became 4:3.

a) How many English books were there in the library?
b) Find the total number of English and Chinese books in the library in the end.

My work.

**Initial Ratio (before)**
English: Chinese
8: 5

**Initial Ratio (after)**
English: Chinese
4:3

*Since English books is the fixed number. I'm guessing we have to times 2 in the  **Initial Ratio (after)**, so....

8: 5 (before)
8: 6 (after)

since 6units - 5units = 1unit

*We know the difference is 50. So 1unit = 50.

a) Since we have 8 units for English. 8 * 50 = **400**.
b) Since we have 8 units for English and 6 units for Chinese. 50 * 14 = **700**

Is my work mathematically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it is correct.

Verification:

Initially we have $8 \times 50= 400$ English books and $5 \times 50= 250$ Chinese books. The ratio was $8:5$.

After which, we have $8 \times 50=400$ English books and $(5+1) \times 50 = 300=250+50$ Chinese books. The ratio is now $8:6=4:3$.

Slower method:

$\frac{E}{C}=\frac{8}{5}$, $\frac{E}{C+50}=\frac{4}{3}=\frac{8}{6}$

$8C=5E, 6E=8C+400$

$E=400$, $C=250$.

Comment: Thank you for the slower method.